# Объединение данных с нескольких репозиториев

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура, rxjava, cleancode

Есть несколько репозиториев

`ObjectRep` - объекты

`ObjTypeRep` - описание типов объектов

`TreeRep` - дерево вложенностей

`MotionRep` - текущие параметры/состояние объекта (данных может и не быть)

На экране дерево объектов нужно показать `join` из всех этих репозиториев.

Как я думал это сделать:

1й вариант) Сделать

```
class ObjectsInteractor @Inject constructor(
    private val objectRepository: ObjectRepository,
    private val treeRepository: TreeRepository,
    private val objectTypesRepository: ObjTypesRepository,
    private val motionRepositry: MotionRepositry
){//.....}
```

и внутри этого интерактора все собирать.
Но это не выгодно, т.к. `ObjectRepository` возвращает `List` объектов и на каждый объект нужно дополнительно запросить `ObjTypeRep` и `MotionRep` (условно в цикле).

2й вариант) Сделать `SuperObjectRepository` из которого будет приходить собранный ответ. Выгода в том, что `SuperObjectRepository` будет получать данные из `Room` (`Select join join`) и выборка всех данных за одну операцию.. Но и есть минус, то, что получается какой-то монстр(выгода которого сразу исчезает если не будет `Room` с его joinами..).

Как быть? Нужно грамотное решение)

Используется:

- Rx
- Kotlin
- Room
- Retrofit

**UP**. Сделал по первому варианту вот так.
В интеракторе есть метод получения "Дерево". Единственное, я не на каждый объект по одному запрашиваю `MotionRep`, а запрашиваю списком и потом соединяю объекты с соответствующими motionState`ами.

Открыт к предложениям по оптимизации кода) p.s. по производительности в любом случае быстрее вариант №2.

```
fun getTreeObjects(parentFolderId: Long): Observable<TreeObject> {
        return treeRepository.getTree(parentId = parentFolderId)
            .flatMapObservable { tree ->
                objectRepository.getObjects(parentFolderId)
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMapObservable { objList ->
                        objList.map { it.id }.let { ids ->
                            motionRepositry.getMotionStates(objectIds = ids)
                                .defaultIfEmpty(emptyList()) //если нет данных то мутируем в пустой список
                                .map { motionState ->
                                    objList.map { obj ->
                                        Pair(
                                            obj,
                                            motionState.findLast { it.objectId == obj.id }
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .map { objects -> TreeObject(tree, objects) }
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
```

Comment: Можно и так и так, узнать наверняка, какой вариант работает быстрее, почти невозможно. А в плане кода - тут уж как Вам удобнее и привычнее.

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж вы используете RX Java используйте ваш первый вариант. Но с одним нюансом. Создайте цепочку запросов с помощью метода combainLatest().

```
Observables.combineLatest(
                    objectRepository.getObjects(parentFolderId),
                    motionRepositry.getMotionStates(objectIds = ids),
                    ::combineData 
                )
```

CombineData это ваш собественный метод в котором вы будете комбинировать ваши данные. Вы можете использовать и более двух аргументов в [combineLatest()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)

Comment: Возможно, приду к решению с combineLatest, но не совсем понятно, откуда при таком подходе получать ids (они приходят из objectRepository.getObjects(parentFolderId)) поэтому я сделал последовательный вызов.

Comment: Ну если одни данные зависят от других, то вам в любом случае придется это последовательно делать